# Real world 3D model using CSS3 / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-animation

I need to rotate/animate 360 deg. a real world 3D object from Smart Phones browsers. When a user scrolls on screen that real world object (e.g. a car) needs to rotate or animate. One option can be replacing images one after another.

Is there any better solution anyone can offer using CSS3/Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

There's a Javascript 3d Library called Three.js - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/
Or if you're looking for something more simple like vectors, you might wanna check out Raphael.js - http://raphaeljs.com

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The first thing is image quality matters. So, I need to use the images of the car anyhow. Building a 3D model of the car is not the solution as it will not be same as images. Any how I need to mimic the 3D models using images only.

Comment: did u succeed in creating a 3D model with images only? I'm too interested in learning how one could do such.

Answer (score 0):

Three.js won't be the best choice for mobile browsers, considering the WebGL implementation is still a desire on iOS Safari even it's not the case with Android. CSS3 is not capable of working with high complexity 3D object manipulation, so from this perspective is somehow limited. It has all the 3D (rotation, scaling and transformation) functionalities but for post processing effects - which can be obtained with shaders - are out of scope.

But there is a nice little library which combine Javascript with CSS3 to create some 3dish effects: http://www.edankwan.com/lab/css3dEarth

I think this is what You need!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As the real world object (car) is very complex to build 3D model I'm planning to go for image solution. Any way I can mimic the 3D model using car images only?

Comment: It's possible and if you are opting for `Three.js` you need to provide canvas as a rendering context, otherwise won't be available in iOS. Though there is one drawback: canvas is somehow off-limited with high rendering context which means could be some dropped frames here and there.